# Flutte google_sign_in issue in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I just created new project and added `google_sign_in: ^4.1.1` dependency in **pubspec.yaml** and try to run the app and getting below error.

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from /Users/ipatel/Desktop/flutter_app_google/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDAuthorizationService+IOS.m:20:
    /Users/ipatel/Desktop/flutter_app_google/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.h:30:1: error: expected ','
    API_UNAVAILABLE(macCatalyst)
    ^
    In module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/ipatel/Desktop/flutter_app_google/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/OIDAuthorizationService.h:19:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.4.sdk/usr/include/os/availability.h:93:171: note: expanded from macro 'API_UNAVAILABLE'
        #define API_UNAVAILABLE(...) __API_UNAVAILABLE_GET_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__,__API_UNAVAILABLE6, __API_UNAVAILABLE5, __API_UNAVAILABLE4,__API_UNAVAILABLE3,__API_UNAVAILABLE2,__API_UNAVAILABLE1, 0)(__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                                                                                                                              ^
    In file included from /Users/ipatel/Desktop/flutter_app_google/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDAuthorizationService+IOS.m:21:
    /Users/ipatel/Desktop/flutter_app_google/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentCatalyst.h:28:26: error: expected ','
    API_AVAILABLE(macCatalyst(13)) API_UNAVAILABLE(ios)
                             ^
    2 errors generated.
    note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description
```

**Flutter Doctor Result:**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.12.13+hotfix.6, on Mac OS X 10.14.3 18D109, locale en-IN)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)

• No issues found!
```

If you want any other from my end then let me know.

Comment: Please, upgrade your Xcode to the latest version (Xcode 11.2.1). This will fix your problem.

Comment: I just open Xcode and hide "API_UNAVAILABLE(macCatalyst)" from 2-3 files and error is gone .. Don't know is it right solution or not ? and upgrade Xcode wont also be right solution BECAUSE my old projects that using with `google_sign_in` those are working well in iOS.

Comment: Do your old projects use the same latest google_sign_in ^4.1.1 framework version?

Comment: No it's google_sign_in: ^4.0.14

Comment: try to downgrade google_sign_in framevork to the same version as at your old projects, run `flutter clean` and try again to build.

Comment: Thanks mate for helping me. First I tried to set down version I thought might be help me but din't get success.